# Wierd camera snapping

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was testing my game, and then when I ran the code the camera started doing weird snapping that made camera movement difficult. Here is the script:

```
public class CameraMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float sensX;
    public float sensY;

    public bool killSwitch;

    public Transform orientation;

    float yRotation;
    float xRotation;

    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        float mouseX = Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse X") * Time.deltaTime * sensX;
        float mouseY = Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse Y") * Time.deltaTime * sensY;

        yRotation += mouseX;
        xRotation -= mouseY;

        xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -90f, 90f);

        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, yRotation, 0);
        orientation.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, yRotation, 0);
    }
}
```

I tried reloading but that didn't work. I'm really confused because it was working a minute ago.

Comment: `camera started doing weird snapping` can you define this a bit more in detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've setup your Input Manager settings incorrectly, you'll likely see a 'Sensitivity' default of `1000`. Which would cause your mouse to be returns hugely large numbers when moving around.

Instead, try a sensitivity of `1` in the Input Manager, and then fine tune it in your Component through the Inspector. The `CameraMovement` component `sensX` and `sensY` were set to `10` in the animation below.

[image: Input Manager]
[image: Example Animation]